# Google search to give day given date

Tags: google-search, calendar

I often want a day given a date. Is there a quick Google query that will immediately give me the calendar day given a date, in the same way that I get an immediate result for the queries `23*35` and `time in China`?

[To clarify, I want a query of the type `day of 22 December 2012` that will return `Saturday`.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly what you are looking for—not a Google solution—, but you can ask Wolfram Alpha for this information. See for example, [what day was May 12, 1862](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=what+day+of+the+week+was+may+12%2C+1862).

Comment: Related, but not a solution: check [this Lifehacker article](http://lifehacker.com/5848651/how-to-quickly-figure-out-the-day-of-the-week-any-date-falls-on) as well.